# Pass object to DLL function imported with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to use an existing library in my python application.
This is a library to read a particular data file.
If you are curious you can download it from here https://www.hbm.com/en/2082/somat-download-archive/ (somat libsie).

The first thing I need to do it open the file so my python scripts starts like:

```
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"libsie.dll")
context = hllDll.sie_context_new()
file = hllDll.sie_file_open(context, "test.sie".encode())
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000009F6C06B8
```

I verified that the .sie file is accessible.
I think the problem lies in the "context" object that gets passed as first argument. I think the type is the issue.

Here is part of the header file where context is defined:

```
typedef void sie_Context;
...
SIE_DECLARE(sie_Context *) sie_context_new(void);
/* > Returns a new library context. */
```

Am I calling these functions correctly?
Is there a problem with passing the context object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `sie_context_new` call succeed?  You're quite sure your DLL and your Python are the same bittedness (32-bit vs 64-bit)?  If you print `context`, what do you see?

Comment: Yes, they are the same bittedness. ```sie_context_new``` runs and gives an int back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 64-bit system, return values default to `c_int` (32-bit).  At a minimum, set the `.restype` to at least a `c_void_p` to indicate a 64-bit pointer is returned.

Ideally, set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function called.

```py
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"libsie.dll")
hllDll.sie_context_new.argtypes = () # optional but recommended
hllDll.sie_context_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p  # add this
hllDll.sie_context_new.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p # guess, need prototype
# hllDll.sie_context_new.restype = ???

context = hllDll.sie_context_new()
file = hllDll.sie_file_open(context, b"test.sie")
```

Comment: defining objects as ```c_void_p``` worked. Now I have another problem. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71358350/loop-through-a-pointer-with-ctypes